# Are the accumulation points of a set and of its closure the same?

Tags: general-topology

I've been studying *Topology, An Introduction with Application to Topological Groups* by McCarty.  I've learned about topological spaces, open and closed sets, accumulation points, and isolated points.  A couple months ago I had a conjecture:

> If $T$ is a topological space and $A \subset T$, and $A^-$ is the
> closure of $A$, then the accumulation points of $A$ equal the
> accumulation points of $A^-$.

I haven't been able to prove or disprove this yet.  I am working with the definition that $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if $x \in (A - \{x\})^-$.  So far, I have convinced myself that the accumulation points of $A$ are accumulation points of $A^-$, but I can't figure out whether the converse is true.  Would somebody like to help me out?

---

What I have so far:

For any $x \in T$, $A - \{x\} \subset A^- - \{x\}$.  Therefore, $(A - \{x\})^- \subset (A^- - \{x\})^-$.  For any accumulation point $x$ of $A$, $x \in (A - \{x\})^-$.  Therefore, $x$ is also an accumulation point of $A^-$.

Comment: Is your definition of closure the smallest closed set that contains $A$?

Comment: If $x$ is an accumulation point of $A^-$, but not of $A$, then you can find an open neighborhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $A\setminus \{x\}$, but that open set must intersect $A^- \setminus \{x\}$. Use that to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Your proof works, provided you have already proven that for a set $S$, a point $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ **if and only if** $x \in \overline {S \setminus \{x\}}$. You use the "if" portion directly in stating $x \in \overline{A \setminus \{x\}}$. From your earler subset deduction, this means $x \in \overline{\overline A \setminus \{x\}}$, and therefore by the "only if" portion, $x$ is an accumulation point of $\overline A$. However if you do not have this result already proven as definition, theorem or exercise, you need to prove both directions here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for your comment.  maybe i can rephrase my question as, "Prove that for any $x$, $x \in (A - \{x\})^-$ if and only if $x \in (A^- - \{x\})^-$."  Or disprove!

Comment: @aangulog yes I'm taking the closure to be the smallest closed set that contains $A$.